# Please help me solve these limits...

Tags: limits

So, I need you to solve one of these limits for me, so I can see how it's done, so I can do the rest myself.

[image]

Comment: Or please explain me everything I need to know to solve them :D

Comment: rationalize the radicals

Comment: @A6Tech This is a homework question.

Comment: It's not, we're doing limits in two classes, I just want to be prepared. The answers below gave me a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, one. Here comes:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{u}-\sqrt{v}}{\sqrt[3]{u}-\sqrt[3]{v}}
=
\frac{u-v}{\sqrt{u}+\sqrt{v}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt[3]{u^2}+\sqrt[3]{uv}+\sqrt[3]{v^2}}{u-v}=
\frac{\sqrt[3]{u^2}+\sqrt[3]{uv}+\sqrt[3]{v^2}}{\sqrt{u}+\sqrt{v}}\underset{u,v\to1}{\longrightarrow}\frac{1+1+1}{1+1}.
$$
Equivalently, when $x\to0$, $(1\pm x)^a=1\pm ax+o(x)$ hence
$$
\frac{(1+x)^a-(1-x)^a}{(1+x)^b-(1-x)^b}=\frac{1+ax-(1-ax)+o(x)}{1+bx-(1-bx)+o(x)}=\frac{2ax+o(x)}{2bx+o(x)}\underset{x\to0}{\longrightarrow}\frac{a}b.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You could multiply by the conjugate over the conjugate (or the appropriate generalization for the nth roots), and do some asymptotics.

eg: $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} (x- \sqrt{x^2-5x} * \frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-5x}}{x+\sqrt{x^2-5x}})$

$= \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{x^2 - x^2+5x}{x+\sqrt{x^2-5x}}$
$= \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{5x}{x+\sqrt{x^2-5x}}$

At this point, notice that 
$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} x+\sqrt{x^2-5x} =\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} 2x $
and substitute, 
to get $5/2$ as the answer.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, to figure out "the appropriate generalization" that i mention, Consider that x^2-y^2 = (x-y)(x+y),  and the generalization you want is x^n-y^n = (x-y)(cyclotomic polynomial of degree n-1 in x and y). It can be derived from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial and then you replace the values with the roots you want. It does get ugly, but it works.